# Regex expression on html image string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm struggling with completing a regex expression, and it would be greatly appreciated if someone could help.

I'm trying to get the source of the image from this HTML div tag

```
<div class="preview item"><img alt=""
    sizes="(max-width: 440px) 320px"
    src= "https://m.testlink.com/test/zx320y230c_4130512.jpg"
    srcset= "https://m.testlink.com/test/zx320y230c_4130512.jpg 320w, https://m.testlink.com/test/zx640y460c_4130512.jpg 640w"></div>
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
const imgRegX = /<div class="?preview item"?[^>]*>\s*<img alt="?" sizes= "?"/g;
```

For some reason when I add the sizes it breaks.

I also assume this is how the src regex would look like, but so far I can't figure out the sizes.

```
src="?([^"\s]+)/
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use elements to get this information from the document without using a RegEx. For example, the below extracts the `src` attribute for all images that are children of the "preview" div.

```js
const previews = document.getElementsByClassName('preview');

for (let item of previews) {
    var images = item.getElementsByTagName('img');
    
    for (let img of images) {
        console.log('Source:', img.src);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="preview item"><img alt=""
    sizes="(max-width: 440px) 320px"
    src= "https://m.testlink.com/test/zx320y230c_4130512.jpg"
    srcset= "https://m.testlink.com/test/zx320y230c_4130512.jpg 320w, https://m.testlink.com/test/zx640y460c_4130512.jpg 640w"></div>
```

## RegEx Problem

Your RegEx problem is caused by an unexpected space here: `src= "` There is a space before the quote, which means it no longer matches your expression. The below screenshot is taken from [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/).

You could cater for the whitespace after the `=` sign in your RegEx:

```
src=\s"?([^"\s]+)
```

[image: RegEx Test]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I cant use document, as its an object of window and the platform Im using is react-native. Sorry for not mentioning it in the question. Also, the space before the src is present in the html as well. @Fenton

Comment: @redberry I've provided an updated RegEx that works for this specific use-case.

Comment: my problem comes from this line 'sizes= "?"/g;', this is where the regex stops working, I think im not handling the search through sizes properly